# Powershell Command Gather OU List

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm attempting to gather information about a list of devices from AD. I want to go through each component and filter out the information to only show if the device is within a specific OU. In this case it would be all computers without a mdt component. So far I'm able to pull the information but it list each component as a line of text and I'm looking to just list if the devices are listed a part of the specific OU.

```
$workstation = "WSAPTKFT00003"

$properties = (get-adcomputer $workstation -Properties *).memberof

$properites_clean = $properties -replace("cn=","") -replace(",OU=Components,OU=ClientManagement,DC=*,DC=rl,DC=*,DC=com","") -replace(",OU=EntitlementGroups,OU=ClientManagement,DC=*,DC=rl,DC=*,DC=com","")

foreach($component in $properites_clean)
    {
        If($component -like '*windows_upgrd*')
            {
                "$workstation has windows upgrade entitled." | Out-File C:\LocalFiles\windows_upgrd.txt -Append
            }
        Else
            {
                "$workstation does not have windows upgrade entitled." | Out-File C:\LocalFiles\windows_upgrd.txt -Append
            }
    }
```

Comment: Why o why are you colecting **all** properties first with `-Properties *` and then cut it down to the single property you actually need?

Comment: How should I go about collecting the properties?

Comment: If you're only interested in the memberof attribute then just use `-properties memberof`

Comment: Also, `-replace` is a regex using **operator**, not a **method**, so you should not place whatever you want to replace inside brackets. Because it uses regex (not wildcards), stuff ike `DC=*` is not doing what you think it should do. This will match _zero or more '=' characters_ and not as you might think any text following the '=' character.